# Excel return INDEX results horizontally with multiple variables

Tags: excel

I am attempting to return a horizontal list of results from a vertical table using a form of the INDEX formula. I have attempted what I have found online and adapted myself, but none seem to work using multiple variables for the row number.

```
Variables in another table:
Project_Group = P2:P290 (This is the result I want from the formula)
Project_Name = B2:B290 (This is cell D5 in the sheet containing the formula)
Task_Title = E2:E290 (This is required to identify project phases)

{=IFERROR(INDEX(Project_Group,SMALL(IF(AND(Project_Name=$D$7,LEFT(Task_Title,4)="Test"),ROW(Project_Group)-MIN(ROW(Project_Group))+1),COLUMNS($E$5:E5))),"")}
```

This is returning the value from Row -3.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: A sample of data (or a link to an uploaded workbook) that can be used to reproduce your problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array formulas do not process AND operators correctly since AND (and OR) are a form of array calculation in themselves. You need to 'nest' the IF conditions.

```
=INDEX(Project_Group, SMALL(IF(Project_Name=$D$7, IF(LEFT(Task_Title,4)="Test", ROW(Project_Group)-MIN(ROW(Project_Group))+1)), COLUMNS($E$5:E5)))
```